# Text doesn't aligned to the center correctly in print media

Tags: html, css, printing

I have an HTML/CSS page, the page look good in the screen, but when I print it some text (composed with 2 lines) doesn't aligned to the center correctly.

[image]

I tried to fix that with padding-left or margin-left without result.

Below is a part of the code:

```css
.tsc_pricingtable02 li.pricing_header1 {
height: 49px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
-webkit-border-radius: 1px 6px 0 0;
-khtml-border-radius: 19px 6px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 19px 6px 0 0;
border-radius: 19px 6px 0 0;
}
.tsc_pricingtable02 ul li {
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
height: 35px;
padding-top: 10px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pricing_column red">
        <li class="pricing_header1">Tooway <br>Lite M</li>
        <li class="pricing_header2">299Dh <span> HT/mois</span></li>
        <li class="odd">10MB</li>
        <li class="even">2MB</li>
        <li class="odd">10GO</li>
        <li class="even"><span class="pricing_yes"></span></li>
        <li class="odd">3000DH</li>
        <li class="even">5200DH</li>
        <li class="odd">600DH</li>
        <li class="pricing_footer"><a href="#" class="tsc_buttons2 black">Sign Up</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't `text-align: center;` and `float:left;` Hoping that it will be centered. It won't be.

You need to have a `<div>` inside your `<li>` that has a `width` and aligned `center`

Here is a sample of what I am talking about...

```
  <ul class="pricing_column red">
    <li class="odd"><div>10MB</div></li>
    <li class="even"><div>2MB</div></li>
    <li class="odd">10GO</div></li>
  </ul>

.tsc_pricingtable02 ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100px; <!--  Gave a real width -->
    height: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left; <!-- kept the align left, but removed align center -->
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.tsc_pricingtable02 ul li div {
    text-align: center; <!-- aligned center -->
    width:100%; <!-- Gave full width -->
}
```

Comment: you are right, the float was the cause of the problem, I fixed it by turned float to none. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the float, I fixed it by setting it to none

```
.tsc_pricingtable02 ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Thank you so much